# What's the result of a single print() function in python

Tags: python

I got a python sublist and a function(replace 0 with .) to print this sublist(Yeah, it's like sudoku). The code is as below.

```html
grid = [[5,3,0,0,7,0,0,0,0], 
        [6,0,0,1,9,5,0,0,0], 
        [0,9,8,0,0,0,0,6,0], 
        [8,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,3], 
        [4,0,0,8,0,3,0,0,1], 
        [7,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,6], 
        [0,6,0,0,0,0,2,8,0], 
        [0,0,0,4,1,9,0,0,5], 
        [0,0,0,0,8,0,0,7,9]]
        
def print_grid():
    for row in grid:
        for column in row:
            if column == 0:
                print("." , end=" ")
            else:
                print(column , end=" ")
```

After I run print_grid(), I got a result like below. I wonder how to print it line by line. Thanks in advance for any kind of help.

```html
 3 . . 7 . . . . 6 . . 1 9 5 . . . . 9 8 . . . . 6 . 8 . . . 6 . . . 3 4 . . 8 . 3 . . 1 7 . . . 2 . . . 6 . 6 . . . . 2 8 . . . . 4 1 9 . . 5 . . . . 8 . . 7 9
```

Comment: Because you are changing the end with ` ` instead of the default new line

Comment: Just print a newline after your inner loop

Answer (score 1):

Add a `print()` at the end of second for loop:

```
grid = [[5,3,0,0,7,0,0,0,0], 
        [6,0,0,1,9,5,0,0,0], 
        [0,9,8,0,0,0,0,6,0], 
        [8,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,3], 
        [4,0,0,8,0,3,0,0,1], 
        [7,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,6], 
        [0,6,0,0,0,0,2,8,0], 
        [0,0,0,4,1,9,0,0,5], 
        [0,0,0,0,8,0,0,7,9]]
        
def print_grid():
    for row in grid:
        for column in row:
            if column == 0:
                print("." , end=" ")
            else:
                print(column , end=" ")
        print()

print_grid()
```

Answer (score 1):

This achieves the result you are looking for in a simpler way, printing each row of the grid "line by line". For each row we use a list comprehension to generate a new list of the row values where 0 is replaced with "." Then using the splat operator (*) we pass this row as arguments which the print statement will print with spaces in between.

```
grid = [[5,3,0,0,7,0,0,0,0], 
    [6,0,0,1,9,5,0,0,0], 
    [0,9,8,0,0,0,0,6,0], 
    [8,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,3], 
    [4,0,0,8,0,3,0,0,1], 
    [7,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,6], 
    [0,6,0,0,0,0,2,8,0], 
    [0,0,0,4,1,9,0,0,5], 
    [0,0,0,0,8,0,0,7,9]]

for row in grid:
    print(*["." if val == 0 else val for val in row])
```

Answer (score 0):

The module `Numpy` is perfect for this.
But also it is required that your print function becomes a board modifying function.

```
grid = [[5,3,0,0,7,0,0,0,0], 
    [6,0,0,1,9,5,0,0,0], 
    [0,9,8,0,0,0,0,6,0], 
    [8,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,3], 
    [4,0,0,8,0,3,0,0,1], 
    [7,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,6], 
    [0,6,0,0,0,0,2,8,0], 
    [0,0,0,4,1,9,0,0,5], 
    [0,0,0,0,8,0,0,7,9]]
    
def change_grid():
    for x in range(9):
        for y in range(9):
            if grid[x][y] == 0:
                grid[x][y] = "." 
change_grid()
print(np.matrix(grid))
```

Answer (score -1):

All you need to do is to change a line everytime you loop through one row.

```
def print_grid():
    for row in grid:
        print("")
        for column in row:
            if column == 0:
                print("." , end=" ")
            else:
                print(column , end=" ")
```

Comment: Your answer produces a less than perfect result.  It prints a blank line, and then leaves the final line dangling without an EOL. @WasifHasan's answer is the better alternative.

Comment: Ah. I see. Thank you for commenting.